# I'm using XMLHttpRequest to upload files and show a progress bar, how can I process the file and read the output?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I've used the tutorial listed here - [File upload progress tutorial](https://www.codingnepalweb.com/file-upload-with-progress-bar-html-javascript/) - to upload files and track the progress of the upload, and it's a very nice solution that works beautifully.

However, I want to be able to process the file once it's uploaded to the server, and, as these are large files, I need to update the user so that he knows something is happening while he waits.

I'm initialising a XMLHttpRequest() using  `let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();`.

Then I open the connection using `xhr.open("POST", "index.php");`.

Then I define my progress routine using `xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", ({loaded, total}) =>{}` which contains the output for the progress bar.

The html form is encapsulated by `let data = new FormData(form);` and then passed on to the server using `xhr.send(data);`.

This is all defined in the tutorial.

However, I don't seem to have any way of reading output from the php script which processes the file on the server.

I've tried

```
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
      console.log(xhr.response);
    }
  }
```

But this produces no output.

Can anybody suggest a way of achieving this?

The php code is this:

```
$index_number=0;
$output="";
if ($_FILES['file']['error'])){
  die('Cannot process file.');
}
$file_name =  $_FILES['file']['name'];
$file_dir = "files/".$_POST['dbname']."/";
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$query="INSERT INTO drawings (name)VALUES('".$file_name."');";
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'dwgman', 'fM6#[psL!dwD8XV+G1', $_POST['dbname']);
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
  $index_number=$mysqli->insert_id;
}
if(!file_exists($file_dir)){
  mkdir($file_dir,0744);
}
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$file_dir.$index_number.".sat");
$command="/var/www/html/dfile/stored "."/var/www/html/dfile/".$file_dir.$index_number.".sat ".$_POST['dbname']." ".$index_number;
passthru($command);
```

Comment: what output? without the PHP code, we can't tell what output you're expecting to see. `xhr.response` or `xhr.responseText` are the likely candidates for reading the servers response

Comment: however, the PHP in that tutorial does not send any response

Comment: I've edited the post to include the PHP, although I'm not sure it adds anything. Basically, I have a program which parses the file and populates the database, reporting its progress as it goes: 10...20...30..., etc. I'd like to capture this output to inform the user.

Comment: where is this code you speak of? I see nothing that produces a progress

Comment: The program is a compiled c program which I've written and which uses a third party library to parse the uploaded file and store elements in a database. The program uses printf to print numbers: a tenth of the way through the file, the program will print "10", halfway through the file the program will print "50" and so on until 100 percent. I need to access this output so that I can show the user the progress.

Comment: Thanks to everybody who looked at this. I feel a complete idiot. The code is working, but the messages I was getting were output to stderr. I could see the output when I ran the program from the command line, but my ajax calls were generating errors which weren't being displayed. Apologies.